# Fluid-width nav in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Working on revamping a client's site, and one of their requests is to change the nav to accommodate text of any size. Here's the trick: **I can't change html, just css and javascript**. Oh, and the version of jquery on the site is 1.4.4 - this can't change either.

I've got a javascript-based solution in place, and it's working across all modern browsers - but I can't seem to get it to function in IE7. The solution relies on all nav elements rendering in their native width (i.e. wrapping instead of resizing), in order to calculate the necessary width changes. In IE7, the nav items don't clear - the last one shrinks to a tiny size to fit into the first row, and the javascript thus can't tell that resizing needs to be calculated.

The javascript should work fine, the main issue is that I need to know what my css isn't doing to force the last element to wrap instead of resize in IE7. I've tried an exhaustive number of combinations of `display: inline-block;`, `white-space: nowrap;`, and `float: left;` to no avail.

I isolated the nav in question and put it in a fiddle [right here](http://jsfiddle.net/D8etp/). If anyone has any ideas, or knows a better way I can implement, let me know - all suggestions welcome!

Comment: I don't see anything happening when you resize the window.  What would be an example of dynamic width text?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - the nav needs to accommodate text of indefinite size. It won't ever change once the page loads, but they want the freedom to change the names in the nav without worrying if it's going to break.

Comment: I'm not sure changing the values of a navigation regularly is a good idea.  And I think you mean the number of characters rather than size (i.e. 28px vs. 100px), though that would pose a similar issue.

Comment: I fully agree with you @hungerstar - but unfortunately, this is the spec I was given and I don't have the power to change it =(

Comment: Oh those pesky clients!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two versions of your jsFiddle here to compare with and verify that this is what you're going for.  I cleaned up your CSS a bit but the main thing I did was set a `percentage width` on the `li` in your navigation.  You have 6 elements so 100/6 = 16.6666%.  I should also not I removed the jQuery in the jsFiddles below.

http://jsfiddle.net/D8etp/1/
and
http://jsfiddle.net/D8etp/2/

*CSS*

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#top-nav{
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 940px;
}
#nav {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    min-height: 49px;
    background-color: #007369;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#nav > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 0 0 0;
    width: 16.6666666666%;
}
#nav > li > a {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7px 12px 17px 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0 4px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#nav > li > a:hover {
    background: #b0a893;
}
#nav > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I should have made a note about the rounding issue.  That's why we love IE right!

Comment: While this is a smart solution, and one that I'd like to be able to use in different circumstances, this doesn't solve my problem - I'd already be done if it was as simple as setting all the nav elements to the same width.

Comment: Turns out I was able to talk them into using this as a fallback for IE7. Cheers!